# Android App keeps closing in android studio

Tags: android

When I run my android studio app, I get the app has stopped working error on the emulator.

These are what the console says:

```js
Duplicate key [Client pid: 8660]
   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key [Client pid: 8660]
   at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$throwingMerger$0(Collectors.java:133)
   at java.util.HashMap.merge(HashMap.java:1254)
   at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$58(Collectors.java:1320)
   at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
   at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
   at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
   at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidProcessHandler$ProcessInfo.onClientListChanged(AndroidProcessHandler.java:175)
   at com.android.tools.idea.run.AndroidProcessHandle
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not post any codes on the question. I am thinking you should have an error on your HashMap method. It has something to do with a duplicate key when you call stream.collect(). To deal with duplicated keys - use other package, e.g: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html
Hope it helps.